# How to integrate a theme in reactjs project

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I have purchased a theme and i want to implement it in my React Project. I added script tags in index.html but they doesnt seem to update the data when component is reload or pressed back. I thought i should install using npm and this is how i imported after installation.

```
import  $ from  'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-select';
import 'jquery.mmenu';
import 'bootstrap-slider';
import '@material/snackbar';
import 'clipboard';
// import 'counterup/jquery.counterup';
import 'magnific-popup';
import 'slick';
import './assets/js/custom.js';
```

But, facing a problem with jQuery in custom.js file [image]

What exactly is the right way to import jQuery and its dependencies into Reactjs Project. How can i integrate third party libraries in Reactjs.

Comment: You should not use jQuery within a react project.

Comment: Those are theme files that are required by the template. I am aware not to use jQuery in react